# Why do colors slightly change when copying from Illustrator to Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, color

I want to copy a object from Illustrator and paste it into a Photoshop document with the same color mode and profile.

[image][image]

When I use the `Eyedropper Tool` on the pasted object in Photoshop the color seems to be slightly off.

[image][image]

**Both the Illustrator and the Photoshop document have their `Color Mode` set to RGB.**

[image][image]

**Both Applications are using synchronized color settings.**

[image]

This also happens when the object is dragged or Placed. It does not happen when copying from Photoshop to Illustrator.

Could there be a problem with my color management settings? What actually happens to the color information, when it is copied from one application to another?

Comment: As I understand the duplicate question, the problem was copying from CMYK to RGB. In my case I am trying to copy from sRGB to sRGB. I don’t think the answers of the duplicate adress my question.

Comment: Ultimately, while design software is in use, this is not a design question. It is far more of a technical support issue and really off-topic due to that. Adobe will be in a better position to assist. One thing to check is the eye dropper tool options in Photoshop. If it is set to a 3x3 or 5x5 sample, it's averaging color, not picking up exact color from a single pixel.

Comment: Ok, I will ask support about it, but thanks anyway.

Comment: For those who are interested: There seems to be a slightly different color management implementation between both applications. It does not happen when you open the .ai directly in Photoshop. It only happens to colors at the edge of the sRGB-gamut.